# What type of Mounting Bracket is this? Where can I purchase it? HP pavillion p6823w

Tags: usb-storage, desktop-customization, hp-pavilion, pci, antenna

I am in the process of upgrading several internal computer components. There are two small brackets at the bottom of the area where the fan is mounted. I would like to add some antenna ports or a USB port to the back of the case, but a search has yielded no results. I have no idea what this is.

[image]

It seems a specific type of bracket is needed, but I have not found anything that even closely resembles this type of bracket. Any help identifying this, or where I might be able to purchase one would be appreciated.
I have attached a picture to the inside of Case - Strange Bracket Mounts Below Case Fan Far Right Corner.
[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help, but none of those brackets look similar to the type of bracket that is below the case fan. I have those types of brackets that are further up on the case, which were used to cover PCI slots. The one below the case has a unique little tab that attaches horizontally over the back of the case.

Comment: On my personal computer, I do not have this ANT plate on the back, but there are two unused slots that can have this exact plate attached to it. There is no card there, or expansion bay. If it helps, the motherboard i am using is a "foxconn 2ab1 alvorix" from an HP pavillion p6823w. I can post additional pictures of the inside of my computer near that area if it helps momentarily. Thanks for assisting.

Comment: That's not a *"bracket"*.  It's merely a *cover plate*.  Depending on the dimensions, the opening could be for a DIN or IDC connector.  This cover plate is intended to convert the opening to a mounting hole for an antenna.  There's another possible opening just below the fan that sill has its *knock-out* plate intact.  Any connector installed in such openings would have a cable to connect to some board.  There's no (expansion board) *"slot"* behind these openings.

Comment: Your photos do not match.  That's a different PC case in each photo.

Comment: @sawdust: I'm aware they are not the same case. I stated this, but they are both identical in design. Both of these PC cases belong to me. They are both HP Pavillion cases and are identical to one another with the exact same setup and bezel.

Comment: I am wondering where I might be able to  purchase a cover plate that looks like this. A search has yielded no results. Either way, thanks for identifying what the cover plate is.